# Finding the biggest number in a list of numbers

Tags: python, beginner

This is the first time I tried to solve a problem and wrote code for it, rather than learning some code and trying out to see what I might be able to do with it. As such, it's not much, but I'd like any tips and help about how I wrote this. Basically, I tried to write a program to find the biggest number in a list of numbers.

```
def main():
    print("Enter a series of numbers separated only by spaces:", end='\t')
    n = input().split()
    n = [int(i) for i in n]
    while len(n) != 1:
        if n[0] > n[1]:
            n.remove(n[1])
        else:
            n.remove(n[0])
    print("the biggest number is: ", n[0])
main()
```

Feedback? Did I do anything kinda noobish?

Answer (score 3):

The most obvious thing I can see is that you *wrote a loop* when one was not needed.

```
largest = max(n)
```

Also, check your boundary conditions. What happens if no numbers are entered?

Comment: hm. I had not learned the max function yet. Are loops something to be avoided whenever you can? I considered lots of if statement, but the downside was the you couldn't enter as many items as you wanted to and it'd contain a lot of nesting.

Comment: Loops are a common source of program errors. You won't be able to avoid them entirely, but definitely look for places where you don't need to write a loop yourself. Python has quite a number of features that help with this; you already found list comprehensions which is great. The [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) standard module has all kinds of fun things in it.

Comment: Besides being a source of program errors, for loops written in pure Python are typically slower than list comprehensions, and functions implemented in C, like `max` and those provided by `itertools`. With large datasets this can make a big difference in performance.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm for finding the maximum value is rather inefficient, as `list.remove` requires `O(N)` time to remove an item from near the start of a list of length N. That means that your overall algorithm (which needs to remove `N-1` items from the list) will take `O(N^2)` time. A better algorithm needs only to look at each item once, comparing it to the largest item seen so far, and will take `O(N)` time.

The built in `max` function will do that for you, but if you wanted to implement it yourself anyway, you could do:

```
def my_max(lst):
    max_val = lst[0]       # initialize with the first value from the list
    for item in lst:       # loop over the items in the list
        if item > max_val: # compare current item with the maximum seen so far
            max_val = item # set new max
    return max_val         # return the max
```

Comment: Many python solutions are similar, in traditional programming we need this kind of code, for a thing, we do in the easiest way like swapping two variables. a, b = b, a

Answer (score 1):

These lines:

```
n = input().split()
n = [int(i) for i in n]
```

can be replaced with:

```
n = list( map(int, input().split()) )
```

Also, `n` is not a great name for a list, it is generally used for numbers.

Comment: As the `print()` function is used, it can be inferred that this is Python 3, so wrapping `list(map(...))` is needed here since we're using `list.remove` and list indexing.